# Looking for a way to overcome 'MemoryError' in Spyder while merging dataframes together

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am running the script below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 


# load all data to respective dataframes
orders = pd.read_csv('C:\\my_path\\orders.csv')
products = pd.read_csv('C:\\my_path\\products.csv')
order_products = pd.read_csv('C:\\my_path\\order_products.csv')


# check out data sets
print(orders.shape)
print(products.shape)
print(order_products.shape)


# merge different dataframes into one consolidated dataframe
df = pd.merge(order_products, products, on='product_id')  
df = pd.merge(df, orders, on='order_id')
```

On the last line of merging the second data frame, I get this result:

```
out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

The file named 'order_products.csv' is around 550MB, 'orders.csv' is 100MB, and 'products.csv' is just 2MB.  I have tried running this process a few times and I always get the MemoryError issue.  It doesn't seem like the files are really, really massive, but I guess it's all relative, because on my old machine, it's just too much.  Is there a simple way to read these files into dataframes in chunks and then merge these together in chunks?

I am working with Spyder 3.3.4, Python 3.7, and Windows 7 on an old ThinkPad.

Thanks.

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your system?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the concept of slicing and chunking. what it says is you've reach the highest possible length of what your computer's ram can take

```
orders_100 = orders[:100]
products_100 = product[:100]
order_products_100 = order_products[:100]
```

Then do pd.merge()

Comment: chunk all your variables